# ASP.Net 404 After Publish Sometimes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publish

I have an MVC project that works fine locally. When publishing it to the dev environment we run into an issue where we get a 404 on one of the pages. The weird part is this only happens sometimes and we can usually fix it by publishing again until it goes away. Only the one page throws the error.

What we have tried so far is:

Got a copy of the project dll in both the working and broken state. Copying in the working dll when its in the error state seems to fix the problem. Yet, when we compare the two dlls they are exactly the same with no differences.

We checked the IIS logs and there are no out of the ordinary errors that would point to a cause.

Kind of stumped at this point. We have a fix like I said, but at this point looking for some peace of mind. Anyone have any ideas on what to look at?

Here is the Index Action

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        localAdmin = false;
        if (!UoW.IsStarted)
        {
            UoW.Start();
        }
        if (SSDSession.PolicyID > 0)
        {
            policyId = SSDSession.PolicyID;
            return SetPolicyInfo();
        }
        if (Request.Cookies.Get("policyId") != null)
        {
            policyId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies.Get("policyId").Value);
            SSDSession.PolicyID = policyId;
        }
        if (policyId == -1 && SSDSession.User.IsPolicyHolder)
        {                
            policyId = bobDao.GetPoliciesByOwnerPartyId(SSDSession.User.PartyID).First().PolicyId;
            SSDSession.PolicyID = policyId;
            return SetPolicyInfo();
        }
        if (policyId == -1)
        {
            if (!System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
            {
                return Redirect("/core/PolicySearch.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                policyId = 244;
                SSDSession.PolicyID = policyId;
                localAdmin = true;
                return SetPolicyInfo();
            }
        }
        else
        {                
            return SetPolicyInfo();
        }
```

And here is the function it calls at the end

```
private ActionResult SetPolicyInfo()
    {
        if (!UoW.IsStarted)
        {
            UoW.Start();
        }
        PolicyOverviewModel polOvModel = new PolicyOverviewModel();
        polOvModel.PoliciesSummaries = PopulatePolicies();
        polOvModel.Policy = _policyDataService.GetPolicyById(policyId);
        polOvModel.PolicyStatements = polOvModel.Policy.PolicyDocuments.Where(x => x.DocumentType == Core.Acord.Enumeration.DocumentType.POLICY_STATEMENT)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated).Take(5);
        polOvModel.PolicyPerformance = _policyDataService.GetPolicyPerformance(policyId, SSDSession.CycleDate);
        polOvModel.SettledEvents = _policyDataService.GetRecentSettledEvents(policyId, null);
        polOvModel.PendingEvents = _policyDataService.GetRecentPendingEvents(policyId, null);
        polOvModel.EventDocId = new List<int>();
        polOvModel.PolicyID = policyId.ToString();
        foreach (SettledEvent setEvent in polOvModel.SettledEvents)
        {
            var settlementDoc = _policyDataService.GetEventConfirmationDocumentByFileName(setEvent.PolicyID, setEvent.EventQueueID.ToString());
            if (settlementDoc != null)
            {
                polOvModel.EventDocId.Add(settlementDoc.ID);
            }
            else
            {
                polOvModel.EventDocId.Add(-1);
            }
        }
        return View("Index",polOvModel);
    }
```

Comment: Did you check all the folders in the published package all the time you get the error

Comment: Yes. The 404 comes up on going to a certain controller's index action. The index view is there and all the code is in place in the dll to lead to it. We can't find anything missing.

Comment: Is there any corner case in your code that returns a wrong view URL. Can you please share the action method code

Comment: Added that code in.

Comment: Is there a possibility that the 404 comes due to policysearch.aspx

Comment: Should you be using aspx ensure that the file is published and it's in the core folder in the root and not inside another folder

Comment: We are using Areas so the file is in the correct folder. All the other areas and index views work fine. This one in particular is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

I grabbed a copy of the full folder structure on the server in both working and broken states. After comparing we found that sometimes Visual Studio just wouldn't publish a reference DLL. Not sure why it was having that issue but we found that the reference was not necessary and worked around it. Now we have published 10+ times and the error doesn't happen.